Patristic philology - editions of byzantine texts
We are aware of the editions of classical texts (ancient Greek and Latin) by Oxford, Teubner, Bude, Loeb. Where should I search for byzantine texts and especially works of Greek Orthodox Holy Fathers (S. Gregory, S. Basil, S. Maximus etc.)? Do we have similar editions?

Perusing through such libraries could help?

This should probably be CW, given it's a resource request. See this question for a model. If you're looking for a variety of different series, this is the way to go. Otherwise, an edit might be in order.

Corpus Christianorum Series Graeca (published by Brepols) is quite good. You may also be interested in Sources Chrétiennes, which includes facing French translations.

I presume the following three sites, used together, could provide a fairly large part of the relevant corpus (the original Greek texts and translations):

The Christian Classics Ethereal Library
Patrologia Graeca
Early Church Texts

